# Can not fill automatically form with mechanize on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, mechanize

I am trying to test mechanize gem. I would like to subscribe to a website using the form. I selected all the elements correctly ( I guess) but the submit button, does not submit the form. When the form is submitted a mail is instantly received. I am a new to the gem, and I am testing registering to a website with a single mandatory field. I am using the webservice for spam mail to check if it works, so every mail field could substitute with anything before @moncourrier.fr.nf and later check if a mail is received on yopmail website, but I got nothing. Do you have any idea why is not working?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require'pry'


agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get('http://blackburnecreek.com/newsletter-registration') do |page|
form=agent.page.forms[1]
button=form.button_with(:value => "Subscribe")
agent.page.forms[1]["EMAIL"]= "testmechanizegem@moncourrier.fr.nf"

agent.submit(form, button)


end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form is not getting submitted, because the actual form uses jquery which submits the form with some extra params. They are unbinding the submit event of form and are performing a ajax request to submit the form instead with an extra param `id`.

You can confirm so by looking at the request being initiated in network tab of your browser it contains following params:

[image]
Also the page runs following javascript which adds the extra id param to the request:

```
function mce_init_form(){
    jQuery(document).ready( function(jQuery) {
      var options = { errorClass: 'mce_inline_error', errorElement: 'div', onkeyup: function(){}, onfocusout:function(){}, onblur:function(){}  };
      var mce_validator = jQuery("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate(options);
jQuery("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").unbind('submit');//remove the validator so we can get into beforeSubmit on the ajaxform, which then calls the validator
      options = { url: 'http://blackburnecreek.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=68692d660a16c9b7e4be6f51e&id=f19ba31349&c=?', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

See the `url:` part in above function. So when you're submitting it via mechanize you're performing an invalid request(no param id).

I guess mechanize doesn't support execution of javascript. I would recommend you to use capybara which uses web drivers like poltergiest that facilitates support for js execution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was losing my mind on it.